# openerp 6.1 make a new rml report

Tags: reporting, odoo

I want to make a specific header and footer in a custom rml report (different from other reports) so I cant change the header/footer section to this company
how to make a new footer to this report that will appear in all report pages

I have make the header as a repeat row in `<blockTable>` but I didn't find any solutions to the footer

this sample of my rml report

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document filename="test.pdf">
  <template pageSize="(842.0,595.0)" title="Test" author="Martin Simon" allowSplitting="20">
    <pageTemplate id="main">
      <pageGraphics>
            <image file="addons/sim/report/org.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="842" height="595"/>
      </pageGraphics>
      <frame id="first" x1="72.0" y1="122.0" width="707" height="404"/>
    </pageTemplate>
  </template>
  <story>
    <blockTable repeatRows="1">
     <tr>
        <td>
            Test Header
        </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>[[ repeatIn(objects,'o') ]]
        <td>
          <para style="Table_20_Contents">

          </para>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
   <para name="footer">
        Test footer
    </para>
  </story>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own header footer on page like this. It repeat all pages of reports.

```
<template title="TEST" author="Hello" allowSplitting="20">
    <pageTemplate id="first">
      <frame id="first" x1="15.0" y1="42.0" width="539" height="758"/>
      <pageGraphics>
           <!-- Header -->
            <image x="14cm" y="25.6cm" height="40.0">[[ company.logo or removeParentNode('image') ]]</image>
                <setFont name="Helvetica" size="10.0"/>
                <drawString x="1cm" y="27.2cm">Main Header</drawString>
                <!-- Order Details -->
                <place x="33" y="18cm" width="530.0" height="205.0">
                    <blockTable colWidths="265,265" style="Table1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Header Value 1</td>
                            <td><para style="normal2-center">Header Value 2</para></td>
                        </tr>
                    </blockTable>
        </place>

                    <!-- footer -->
        <place x="33" y="55cm" width="530.0" height="205.0">
                <blockTable colWidths="265" style="Table1">
                            <tr><td><para style="normal2-center">Footer Value</para></td></tr>
                        </blockTable>
                    </place>
        </pageGraphics>
    </pageTemplate>
  </template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked I have one question if you can help me in it,I worked before in crystal report is there is a tool that can help me in it also in crystal report I have report header and report footer and page header and page footer and a repeat area to display table is there is something like that in openerp